# Android User Login with Retrofit

Tags: java, android, postman, retrofit

I am trying to use my own login api via retrofit. The Problem is, if username and password is correct, nothing happens and a toast with the message doesn't appears. But if the username and password is wrong, i get a right response and the toast with the correct message appears?

[Retrofit Client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K08bu.png)

[Postman Response 1 (Login not successful)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I42Jc.png)

[Postman Response 2 (Login successful)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqkl2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
        if(response.isSuccessful()){
            ResObj resObj = response.body();
            if(resObj.getMessage().equals("true")){
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "The username or password is incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
         } 
         else {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error! Please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
    }
```